# Check for Soundcard with PyAudio when Soundcard is present or removed

Tags: python, pyaudio

Checking for specific soundcard works as expected with PyAudio, however when I remove soundcard with script running (noddy loop shown below) it cannot detect that the soundcard has been physically removed. The OS system (Windows-7) recognises the system change, however the get_device_info function below always returns with the removed soundcard details even though its not connected.

Surely re-importing pyaudio as shown below in the function you would expect that looking for the removed soundcard should not show up?

Any ideas whats going on??

```
for x in range(100):

     get_soundcard_dev_info()
     var = raw_input("\nPress Enter - to recheck if Soundcard exsists")

def get_soundcard_dev_info():
   import pyaudio 
   pad_sc = pyaudio.PyAudio()
   max_devs = pad_sc.get_device_count()
   input_devices_index = []
   output_devices_index = []

   for i in range(max_devs):
       devinfo = pad_sc.get_device_info_by_index(i)
       if "TUSBAudio ASIO Driver" in devinfo['name']:
           input_devices_index.append(int(devinfo['index']))
           output_devices_index.append(int(devinfo['index']))

   if not input_devices_index:
      print "NONE"

   print input_devices_index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to `import` the same module repeatedly, Python does nothing (because it knows the module is already in `sys.modules`), therefore the PortAudio library is not reloaded and the list of devices is not updated.

Therefore, you can move `import pyaudio` to the top of the file.

I'm not quite sure what happens if you call `pyaudio.PyAudio()` repeatedly (obviously it doesn't do what you expect), but to be sure, you should call this at the end of `get_soundcard_dev_info()`:

```
pad_sc.terminate()
```

This should properly unload the PortAudio library and next time the list of devices should hopefully be correct.